# Loop in a Loop - Vba

Tags: vba, loops, nested-loops

I'm struggling to get this exercise done therefore I'm asking for your help.

I have a table with data as following:

[picture with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnsu9.png)

I need 2 loops:

- 1, one looping Column "BX" from last row to 2 and searching for 2 values (first day of a week
  and last day of a week) in Column BV. Then subtracting corresponding values from Column "BW".

  - Example: Number 37 is last row value ("BX") which should be looked up in Column "BV" (twice),
    get corresponding values: 15,5 and 14,25. Subtract them and get result.
- 2, second one would be going into any free column (i.e. "BZ") and inserting results of previous
  subtractions one by one.

First part is done with a following code:

```
lastc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, lastc).End(xlUp).Row
lastr2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, lastc - 2).End(xlUp).Row

For R = lastr To 2 Step -1
lastr = R

Set FindRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastc - 2), ws.Cells(lastr2, lastc - 2)).Find(What:=ws.Cells(R, lastc))
FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
Set CellPosition = Cells(FindRowNumber, lastc - 1)
Set FindRow2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastc - 2), ws.Cells(lastr2, lastc - 2)).Find(What:=ws.Cells(R, lastc), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Find RowNumber2 = FindRow2.Row
Set CellPosition2 = Cells(FindRowNumber2, lastc - 1)

Next R
```

But I struggle to incorporate second loop and move results where I want them to.

Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added operations to your code to accumulate and output results:

```
Sub test1()
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ws.Columns("BZ").ClearContents  ' clear output column
    
    lastc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lastc).End(xlUp).Row
    lastr2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lastc - 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim col As New Collection   'declare and create collection for results accumulation
    
    For R = lastr To 2 Step -1
        lastr = R
        
        Set FindRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastc - 2), ws.Cells(lastr2, lastc - 2)).Find(What:=ws.Cells(R, lastc))
        FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
        Set CellPosition = ws.Cells(FindRowNumber, lastc - 1)
        Set FindRow2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastc - 2), ws.Cells(lastr2, lastc - 2)).Find(What:=ws.Cells(R, lastc), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        FindRowNumber2 = FindRow2.Row
        Set CellPosition2 = ws.Cells(FindRowNumber2, lastc - 1)

        col.Add CellPosition2 - CellPosition    ' accumulate results in the collection
    Next R
    
    ' output previously accumulated results one-by-one
    cnt = 2 'skip header row
    For Each col_element In col
        ws.Cells(cnt, "BZ") = col_element
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

> In my opinion, an additional output loop is unnecessary, it would be
> more correct to output the results in the same line as the processed
> value in the "BX" column for a visual comparison of the processed
> value and the result

**Option 2**

```
Sub test2()
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ws.Columns("BZ").ClearContents  ' clear output column
    
    lastc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lastc).End(xlUp).Row
    lastr2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lastc - 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For R = lastr To 2 Step -1
        lastr = R
        
        Set FindRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastc - 2), ws.Cells(lastr2, lastc - 2)).Find(What:=ws.Cells(R, lastc))
        FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
        Set CellPosition = ws.Cells(FindRowNumber, lastc - 1)
        Set FindRow2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastc - 2), ws.Cells(lastr2, lastc - 2)).Find(What:=ws.Cells(R, lastc), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        FindRowNumber2 = FindRow2.Row
        Set CellPosition2 = ws.Cells(FindRowNumber2, lastc - 1)
    
        ws.Cells(R, "BZ") = CellPosition2 - CellPosition ' output results
    Next R
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,

thank you very much for correct answer. Much appreciated.

Could you please clarify Dims for New Collection possibility? 
I am working with option explicit and col_element and ctn must be dimed as well.

Comment: `col_element` can be declared as Variant, `cnt` as Integer or Long

Comment: hmm, I assumed that correctly.  However I am getting result value as TRUE/FALSE instead of calculation.

Comment: Please, update your code (in the question) that produced TRUE/FALSE